# Error thrown in IE when OnKeyPress event is triggered on a button control of custom edit form

Tags: sharepoint-online, asp.net, edit-form, jquery-ajax

Error:

> Accessing the 'caller' property of a function or arguments object is
>   not allowed in strict mode

On the click of the same button action, I am starting some workflows and at the end, I am trying to submit the form by triggering the `OnKeyPress` event. This error surfaces only in IE11 and edge. It works just fine in Chrome.

Button:

```
<input type="button" value="Resubmit" name="SubmitBack" Class="btn btn-primary" id="resubmit" style="display:none" onkeypress="javascript:{ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={*redirectionurl*}')}"  ></input>
```

Script for `OnClick` function from which I am triggering `OnKeyPress`:

```
setTimeout(function() {
            subId = '8551c477-e9ac-4aab-a012-5e92f7c44ca2';          

            startWorkflow(itemId, subId).then(function() {


                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#resubmit').keypress();
                }, 7000);
                deffered.resolve();
                return true;

            }, function() {
                deffered.reject();
            });
        }, 2000);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add line of code below before OnKeyPress event.

```
'use strict';
```

If you want to start a workflow before submit the form, I suggest you use REST API + jQuery Ajax to achieve it. To make the request synchronization, we can set **async:false** in the Ajax call. Then execute the OnkeyPress event or submit the form using REST API.

**More information**: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-trigger-sharepoint-2013-designer-workflow-on-a-list-item-by-calling-rest/